# San Disk Cruzer Glide 32 GB and 8Gb can't be copied to.

Tags: usb-drive

I have Ubuntu 12.04 with a kernal of 3.0.0-17-generic (#30-Ubuntu SMP Thu Mar 8 17:34:21 UT
When I tried to copy files to a San Disk Cruzer 8gb usb drive, the copy process went a short way and then completely stopped. Although I have copied items to the USB drive from my PC before, this time the files would start quickly enough but always stop shortly after starting. I figure the 8 gb was bad, so I went and got a brand new 32 gb usb drive from a store, unpackaged it and plugged it in, still unable to copy to the usb drive.

So is there some kind of incompatibility or issue where San Disk Cruzer Glides are no longer supporting it. Is there an obscure setting that I am missing? Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Seems to be working now see comment to answer below.

Comment: @mrtipale you need `ddrescue`, not `dd`. But I don't know why you chose to add a bounty to an unrelated question rather than ask a new question.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following command in terminal,to copy files from source to destination,

```
sudo cp -Ri /path/to/source/folder1 /path/to/destination/folder2/
```

folder1-   folder consists of files in which you are going to copy
folder2-  folder where you are going to paste folder1

Comment: Seems to have just started working normally. However I suspect there is some kind of issue with reading the directory structure. Other issues encountered were trying to delete a file from the USB and being told it couldn't because there was no such file, when there was, and a folder suddenly disappearing, but reappearing when the USB was viewed on a Windows PC and then viewable again when viewed on an Ubuntu machine.

Answer (score 0):

I can't find the document, but I remember a while back where there was a bug with the USB 3.0 driver, it was either a 3.0 in a 2.0 port or vice versa that was giving an issue.

The issue stemmed down to debian and the kernel. I would advise updating the kernel/Os or trying a USB 2.0 drive